# It is possible to forbid childclass to define a class?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, restriction

Hello I am working with unity 3D making my own networking with lidgren.

I had this problem one time too when I made a custom gui for me but was not big problem. A small warning to other developer was little help.

But this time I need better solution.

Lets say I have a BaseClass and a Child:

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehavior {
    void Update() {
        //my connectionhandler
    }
}

public class Child : BaseClass {

    // forbid it to define Update
    void Update() {

    }

    // or let him use it but without writing base.Update() it should still use BaseClass Update()

}
```

As you see in both classes I have void Update(). That problem is if the child uses void Update as well so the base Update does not get called anymore. Is possible to avoid it. Example restrict access to Update Method if base already defined it?
Or it is possible to let child use definition of void Update() but baseclass should also be able to use his own Update() (background working :P)

The other developer should not use everytime base.Update(). I am sure they will forget this many times :)

Comment: You would add sealed to the meathod

Comment: Have you considered adding events to the Update method instead? Allow the consumers to add BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate event handlers to run custom code, but the Update itself would always run?

Comment: No, if I would then I would let them use base.Update() :).  The problem is unity itself. I didn't notice that Update() working else as self defined function. I cannot prevent it. I am thinking now about threading. But its not much safe

Comment: You could make the CS0108 warning an error by setting the "Treat warnings as errors" to "Specific Warnings" to "0108".  It's still not a perfect solution since the error will tell the devs to add "new" to the method.  It would at least mean that they could no longer ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `sealed` keyword, which prevents a further-derived class from overriding a `virtual` method.

Comment: Unfortunately Mono does not define `Update()` as a virtual method, it is not defined at all and it actually uses reflection to call the `Update()` function.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Interesting.  Would `private` work? (do they pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic`?)

Comment: Yes, [it does](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/33828/public-or-private.html).

Comment: Well I see unity doesn't make possible for me. I mean I can define to both void Update with or without virtual. It's same.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but you can handle it with a run time check.  As implemented it would only run on debug builds, but that should mean that the developers will get an error if they at least run their own code.

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehavior {
    void Update() {
        //my connectionhandler
    }

    public BaseClass() {
        Debug.Assert(!OverridesUpdateMethod(), "Do not override Update()!");
    }

    [Debug]
    private bool OverridesUpdateMethod() {
        return GetType() != typeof(BaseClass) &&
               GetType().GetMethod("Update", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks. I will test it. Unfortunately I made already one with threads (more with timer and intervals). It working good but its also ugly :)